# Swift error when trying to access Dictionary: `Could not find member 'subscript'`

Tags: swift

This won't compile:
[image]
I've tried a couple different things; different ways of declaring the Dictionary, changing its type to match the nested-ness of the data. I also tried explicitly saying my `Any` was a collection so it could be subscripted. No dice.

```
import UIKit


import Foundation

class CurrencyManager {

    var response = Dictionary<String,Any>()
    var symbols = []


    struct Static {
        static var token : dispatch_once_t = 0
        static var instance : CurrencyManager?
    }

    class var shared: CurrencyManager {
        dispatch_once(&Static.token) {  Static.instance = CurrencyManager() }
        return Static.instance!
    }

    init(){
        assert(Static.instance == nil, "Singleton already initialized!")
        getRates()

    }


    func defaultCurrency() -> String {

        let countryCode  = NSLocale.currentLocale().objectForKey(NSLocaleCountryCode) as String
        let codesToCountries :Dictionary = [ "US":"USD" ]

        if let localCurrency = codesToCountries[countryCode]{
            return localCurrency
        }

        return "USD"

    }

    func updateBadgeCurrency() {

        let chanCurr = defaultCurrency()

        var currVal :Float = valueForCurrency(chanCurr, exchange: "Coinbase")!

        UIApplication.sharedApplication().applicationIconBadgeNumber = Int(currVal)

    }

    func getRates() {
        //Network code here
        valueForCurrency("", exchange: "")
    }

    func valueForCurrency(currency :String, exchange :String) -> Float? {
        return response["current_rates"][exchange][currency] as Float
    }


}
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Let's take a look at

```
response["current_rates"][exchange][currency]
```

`response` is declared as `Dictionary<String,Any>()`, so after the first subscript you try to call another two subscripts on an object of type Any.

**Solution 1.** Change the type of response to be a nested dictionary. Note that I added the question marks because anytime you access a dictionary item you get back an optional.

```
var response = Dictionary<String,Dictionary<String,Dictionary<String, Float>>>()

func valueForCurrency(currency :String, exchange :String) -> Float? {
    return response["current_rates"]?[exchange]?[currency]
}
```

**Solution 2.** Cast each level to a Dictionary as you parse. Make sure to still check if optional values exist.

```
var response = Dictionary<String,Any>()

func valueForCurrency(currency :String, exchange :String) -> Float? {
    let exchanges = response["current_rates"] as? Dictionary<String,Any>

    let currencies = exchanges?[exchange] as? Dictionary<String,Any>

    return currencies?[currency] as? Float
}
```

Comment: Any reason why this wouldn't work? `let exchanges = response["current_rates"] as Dictionary?`

Comment: I get "Could not find an overload for subscript that accepts supplied arguments"

Comment: I added a second solution. To use that method you just need to put the question mark after "as" instead of after "Dictionary"

Comment: Any way of doing this without hardcoding nested types? (i.e. my comment to Alex's answer)

Comment: The types for `response` don't need to be hardcoded in solution 2. You just need to cast to the correct dictionary type directly before accessing an element.

Comment: How would I change the representation of these types to accommodate something like this? `let symbols = response["symbols"] as? Array`

Comment: Just add the element type: `let symbols = response["symbols"] as? Array<ElementType>`

Answer (score 3):

You can get nested dictionary data by following these steps:

```
let imageData: NSDictionary = userInfo["picture"]?["data"]? as NSDictionary
let profilePic = imageData["url"] as? String
```

Answer (score 2):

```
func valueForCurrency(currency :String, exchange :String) -> Float? {
    if let exchanges = response["current_rates"] as? Dictionary<String,Any> {
        if let currencies = exchanges[exchange] as? Dictionary<String,Any> {
            return currencies[currency] as? Float
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`response` is declared as such:

```
var response = Dictionary<String,Any>()
```

So the compiler thinks `response["current_rates"]` will return an `Any`. Which may or may not be something that is subscript indexable.

You should be able to define you type with nested Dictionaries, 3 levels and eventually you get to a float. You also need to drill in with optional chaining since the dictionary may or may not have a value for that key, so it's subscript accessor returns an optional.

```
var response = Dictionary<String,Dictionary<String,Dictionary<String,Float>>>()
// ... populate dictionaries
println(response["current_rates"]?["a"]?["b"]) // The float
```

Comment: The problem is not all objects in the entire hierarchy follow those generics. Somewhere there may be an array, and I don't want to hardcode the entire interpretation of the JSON in this code.

Comment: Then you will need to check types and cast things at runtime.

Comment: The thing is, I know the specific types *of the elements I want*, and I'd like to ignore other ones. If I access ["current_rates"], I know I will ***always*** get a dictionary.